# Dynamic Templates or Headers on Page Route within Cloudscribe

Tags: cloudscribe

I'd like to be able to customize the layout that is used for the views based on the content page I'm on. For example, if I'm on the homepage, I may want to have a header that originally does not render, but onscroll, appears and is a different color based on the layout of the homepage. It would be great if I can do this on other pages or, at the very least, override view rendering by using Razor on the server side. I wasn't sure if the custom view templates were another option or not. I'm a noob when it comes to this project so any pointers are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For convenience all of the cloudscribe core and cloudscribe SimpleContent views are compiled into Razor class library nugets. But any views that you want to customize can be copied from the corresponding github repo into your project local views and the local views will always take precedence. This way you can customize any views. In fact you can even customize views per theme by copying the views in the theme specific views folder.

So for example if your home page is using SimpleContent, then you could copy the [Page/Index](https://github.com/cloudscribe/cloudscribe.SimpleContent/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.SimpleContent.CompiledViews.Bootstrap4/Views/Page/Index.cshtml) view into your local project. Create a Page folder under Views folder and copy the Index view there and you can add any custom logic or additional partial views. You can also conditionally add javascript or css into the @Section Scripts{} or @Section Style {} if needed. You can inject your own custom services into the view to encapsulate whatever logic you want to use. Depending on what you want to do you may also need to override the PageDetailPartial view.

The main _Layout.cshtml is already in your project and there is one per theme folder. So you can already customize the main layout. You could also create additional layout files and set the the layout to be used from the main view. ie:

```
@{
    Layout = "_MyCustomLayout";
 }
```

or even add some conditional logic to use a different layout per url. This overrides the default Layout which is set from _ViewStart.cshtml. You can also put a _ViewStart.cshtml file in any views sub folder ie Page folder mentioned above to make all the views in that folder use a specific layout. Setting the layout from the view can only be done for main views not from partial views.

EDIT: for additional question in comments about routing

cloudscribe SimpleContent uses conventional routing with named routes. In our project templates you will see in the /Config/RoutingAndMvc.cs extension methods that add the default routes. If you want to change the routing you can comment those out and add the routes yourself using the same route names. The easiest way would be to copy the code from those extension methods into your own extension methods and modify them as you wish, then use your extension methods instead. You can find the SimpleContent routes [here](https://github.com/cloudscribe/cloudscribe.SimpleContent/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.SimpleContent.Web/StartupExtensions.cs)

cloudscribe Core just uses the default route matching on controller and action, it doesn't register routes, just uses normal conventions.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Just wanted to confirm that I *should* be able to do that. Is there a best practice for targeting specific routes/pages? Or just the typical MVC/Razor conventions.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add info about the routing.